# Firefox using default icon stored in /usr/share/icons/

Tags: firefox, icons

I would like to change the icon that Firefox uses.

I just noticed that *Firefox-ESR* ignores its own icons that are downloaded with it (stored in: `/home/user/.local/bin/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/`)

And instead it uses the ones stored in this path: `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps`

Waterfox follows the same file structure as Firefox, and I can change Waterfox's icon simply by changing the icons in the folder `/home/user/.local/bin/waterfox/browser/chrome/icons/default/`

How can I make Firefox use its own default icons (not the theme ones)?

Comment: If I delete the firefox icon stored in `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps` then Firefox launches without an icon (I can see a blank window icon in the taskbar).

Comment: The icon with which an application is identified in the menu system is set in the .desktop file of the application.